# Pipenv lock: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 (Windows 10)

Tags: pipenv

I am trying to lock a pipfile and I am getting the following error (on Windows 10).  Any tips on how to resolve this?  I have tried updating pipenv, wheel, and setuptools.

The code is pulled from a repo which works fine for others.

```
(backend-xuJm__V5) C:\Users\murey\PennLabs\penn-courses\backend>pipenv lock
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Success!
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Locking Failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/users/murey/.virtualenvs/backend-xujm__v5/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/users/murey/.virtualenvs/backend-xujm__v5/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 119, in main
    parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages)
  File "c:/users/murey/.virtualenvs/backend-xujm__v5/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 85, in _main
    requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
  File "c:/users/murey/.virtualenvs/backend-xujm__v5/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
    req_dir=requirements_dir
  File "C:\Users\murey\.virtualenvs\backend-xuJm__V5\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
    req_dir=req_dir,
  File "C:\Users\murey\.virtualenvs\backend-xuJm__V5\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
  File "C:\Users\murey\.virtualenvs\backend-xuJm__V5\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 385, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)

...

  File "C:\Users\murey\.virtualenvs\backend-xuJm__V5\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\murey\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpek28ezzybuild\uwsgi\
```